# I want change the default button text in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

i want to change the default text on the button in the newpost.aspx page but i couldn't find the button on the page . when i select the button the whole webpart is highlighted.
please help me on .

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a "setting" that allows you to do that. Most likely you would have to use some jQuery/Javascript to do this.

Comment: +1. To add: in SharePoint Designer, usually you can customize page partually - only the code inside WebPartZone tag. So possible solution would be to add content editor webpart to the page, and then add script tag inside, and use jquery/javascript to change the button caption.

Comment: how I can find button related id and style from the webprt

Comment: The simplest way would be to view the source of the page. In IE this is done easily by right-clicking the page and selecting "View Source" this will give you the HTML of the page and then you can locate the tag of the button. In a normal OOTB form, the following jQuery works for me: $("input[name*='SaveItem']").attr("value", "Fun Button Title");